# How to mask/change format of data in a view?

Tags: mysql

Is there a inbuilt function that masks output data in a view?

For instance, if I gave the following string in a database

```
119902
```

and I want the output in a view to be something like

```
01.19-9/02
```

Is there a inbuilt function I could use to make the mask as `##.##-#/##`?

Comment: View! So are you using a Famework? If so please say which one

Comment: I don't think there is a MySQL solution. For future reference there is a regex solution for MariaDB: `REGEXP_REPLACE('119902','^([0-9])([0-9]{2})([0-9])([0-9]{2})$','0\\1.\\2-\\3/\\4')`. It ain't pretty but does the job.